# TransitLayer in react-google-maps

Tags: google-maps, reactjs

How can I incorporate google maps TransitLayer using react-google-maps? I see that TransitLayer needs an instance of the map, like this:

```
    var transitLayer = new google.maps.TransitLayer();
    transitLayer.setMap(map);
```

However, I am not sure how to get the instance, as I am using wrappers GoogleMap and withGoogleMap.